# Java 8 Group Objects by a common sub-object

Tags: java

Suppose I have a List of objects coming from the DB, in the following format

```
public class DBEvent {
    private String guiEventId;
    private String guiEventColor;
    private int questionId;
    private Date date;
    // + Getters/setters...
}
```

`List<DBEvent>` holds the following, with some tabular data repeated. I need to group all entries by the same GuiEventId/GuiEventColor, and split the differing QuestionId/Date. This can be a new object list.

[image]

Goal:

```
public class NewEvent {
   private String guiEventId;
   private String guiEventColor;
   private Date date1;
   private Date date2;
}
```

In other words I need to capture the differing Date (Row 1/2 for each pair) while keeping the rest of the info the same, and have that as an object.

Java 8 has some Stream/Filtering functions, would they help here? Or do I need to go to the DB and restructure my SQL query?

Comment: `Stream` aren't so useful when you need context (i.e. "what was the previous stream element with the same id"). Assuming every `gui_event_id` always has exactly two rows I think I'd just make sure the `List<DBEvent>` is sorted by `gui_event_id,questionid` (by the DB, doing it in your app would be wasteful) and then use a plain old `while(iterator.hasNext())` loop consuming two `DBEvent` at each iteration.

Comment: If the sample data provided is representative it's also sad how much redundancy there is, and keeping the previous assumptions in mind it looks like both lines could be replaced by a single one without a `questionid` but with two date columns, one set at insertion time and the second updated later.

Comment: Are elements which should create pairs are guaranteed to be one after another and in specific order? In that case simple loop which would iterate over those pairs would be easier to write and understand than stream solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group items by a value that you compute from collection elements. For example, to group events by `guiEventId`, you can call:

```
List<DBEvent> events = ...//get events
Map<String, List<DBEvent>> groupedEvents = 
    events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(event -> event.getGuiEventId()));
```

This produces a map with all encountered event IDs mapped to the list of corresponding event objects. If you're sure that event ID and color go in consistent pairs, then it's redundant to include color in grouping key (though that would be as easy to change).

Now, with the given groups of event pairs, what you want to do is convert a list of any 2-element list into a single element. For that you can convert value lists into events of the new type:

```
//define a function that takes a list of events and produces a new event:
private NewEvent createNewEvent(List<DBEvent> events) {
    NewEvent evt = new NewEvent();
    evt.setGuiEventId(events.get(0).getGuiEventId());
    evt.setGuiEventColor(events.get(0).getGuiEventColor());
    evt.setDate1(events.get(0).getDate());
    evt.setDate2(events.get(1).getDate());

    return evt;
}
```

Now you can just map values in the db event list map's value collection to `NewEvent`:

```
List<NewEvent> newEvents = 
    groupedEvents.values().stream().map(eventList -> createNewEvent(eventList))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The following points should be noted:

- I assumed that you will inevitably get a pair of events for any given ID. If this is not guaranteed, you may need to validate or change logic to avoid bugs or index out of bounds errors
- If you had multiple entries per event ID, you would have had to use `Stream.reduce`, to perform a pair-wise merging into a new event (but then you'd have had to do it in 2 steps as reduce yields the same type)

Comment: or simpler: `Collectors.groupingBy(NewEvent::getGuiEventId)`

Comment: But unfortunately sorting broke. When I collect into a HashMap using groupingBy(), the original "order by .. ASC" is disregarded. I would need to collect into a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @geneb. If you need to preserve order, then you may need to call `.ordered()` on the stream, then, use `reduce` instead of grouping. All of this is only needed if the order you want cannot be reconstructed, say by invoking `Collections.sort` on the final list you currently have.